# How to exclude statement from looping?

Tags: java, loops

I was asked to display a program that only counts up to 50.

My problem is that when the input exceeds 50 the statement "Number must be below to 50!" is still printed from loops.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter=0;
        int num = input.nextInt();

        for (int i=0; i<=num; i++) 
        {
            if (num >= 0 && num<=50) {
                System.out.print (i + " ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print ("Number must be below 50!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

For some reason, if the user's input exceeds to 51, the output becomes:

```
Number must be below to 50!Number must be below to 50!Number must be below to 50!......
```

How do I exclude the statement from looping?

Comment: If you don't want the message to be displayed multiple times, the simplest approach is to move the statement that displays it outside the loop.

Comment: When you say "For some reason" - the reason is "because that's what your code says to do". Your `if` statement condition doesn't depend on `i` at all... did you intend it to? If you're surprised by how your code executes at the moment, you might want to step through it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following code should give you the desired result:

```java
System.out.println("Enter a number below 50:");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = input.nextInt();

if (num < 50)
{
    System.out.println("Counting down from " + num);
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }
}
else System.out.print("Number must be below 50!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the loop inside the `if` statement.

Pseudocode:

```
if(num >= 0 and num<=50){
  loop...
else
  print("num must be below 50")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the use of line.

```java
class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter=0;
        int num = input.nextInt();
        if(num>50) {
            System.out.print ("Number must be below 50!");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=num; i++)
        {
            if (num >= 0 && num<=50) {
               System.out.print (i + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove the if-statement inside the loop? It doesn't check for anything the loop doesn't check for first.